# How to compare two array objects and remove matched objects from one array object

Tags: javascript

My Code Scenario is:

```
var Employees= [{name:"Ram",htno:1245},{name:"mohan",htno:1246},
{name:"madhu",htno:1247},{name:"ranga",htno:1248}]

var seletedEmployees= [{name:"mohan"},{name:"ranga"}];

var employeesdataAfterremoveSelected = [?];
```

Comment: What you've tried?

Comment: Try this `Employees.filter(emp => seletedEmployees.every(semp => semp.name !== emp.name))`

Comment: Can you make the question more clear? Right now its just code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store selected employees names in an array and then filter Employees array and check if employee's name is in this array:

```js
var employees= [{name:"Ram",htno:1245},{name:"mohan",htno:1246},{name:"madhu",htno:1247},{name:"ranga",htno:1248}]
var selectedEmployees= ["mohan","ranga"];
var result = employees.filter(emp => selectedEmployees.includes(emp.name));
console.log(result);
```

To programatically get array of strings instead array of objects, you can use `map`:

```
var seletedEmployees= [{name:"mohan"},{name:"ranga"}].map(emp => emp.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var Employees = [{name:"Ram",htno:1245},{name:"mohan",htno:1246},
    {name:"madhu",htno:1247},{name:"ranga",htno:1248}] 

var seletedEmployees = [{name:"mohan"},{name:"ranga"}];

var employeesdataAfterremoveSelected = Employees.filter(name => {
  return (name.name !== seletedEmployees[0].name && name.name !== seletedEmployees[1].name)
}) 

console.log(employeesdataAfterremoveSelected)
```

Comment: if i want to remove one more element instead of var seletedEmployees = [{name:"mohan"},{name:"ranga"}]; i want to delete var seletedEmployees = [{name:"mohan"},{name:"ranga"},{name:"Rambabu"}];  how can I achieve without hard coded inde values as [0] , [1] ....

Answer (score 1):

From the code you have given above i think this might work

```
$.each(student, function(key, value){
   if(matchedvalues.indexOf(value.name) < 0)
     {
       employeesdataAfterremoveSelected.push(value.name);
     }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner, decomposed to explain :

```
// Start by filtering the first array on a condition.
employeesdataAfterremoveSelected = Employees.filter(
  // Map the array of selected employees to only return the name
  e => seletedEmployees.map(_e => _e.name)
    // use the includes function to check if the name is in the array
    .includes(e.name)
);
```

In one line :

```
employeesdataAfterremoveSelected = Employees.filter(e => seletedEmployees.map(_e => _e.name).includes(e.name));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter method, something like below (not tested)

```
var Employees = [{name:"Ram",htno:1245}, {name:"mohan",htno:1246}]

var SelectedEmployess = [{name:"Ram",htno:1245}]

// filter the items from the invalid list, out of the complete list
    var employeesdataAfterremoveSelected = Employees.filter((item.name) => {
    return !SelectedEmployess.has(item.name);
})

// get a Set of the distinct, valid items
var validItems = new Set(employeesdataAfterremoveSelected);
```

Answer (score 0):

var Employees= [{name:"Ram",htno:1245},{name:"mohan",htno:1246},
{name:"madhu",htno:1247},{name:"ranga",htno:1248}]

var seletedEmployees= [{name:"mohan"},{name:"ranga"}];

var employeesdataAfterremoveSelected = Employees.filter(function(val,index) { console.log(val.name)
  return !(seletedEmployees.map(function(e) { return e.name; }).indexOf(val.name));
});